# Back to table view from detail page without reload, Swift

Tags: swift

My table view has detail button for each cell. When I click the button, it will go to detail page about that cell. In the detail page, there is a "back" button. When I click it, it can go back to table view, but the table view is reloaded. My question is how can I go back without reload the table view. I just want to go back to the cell where I click the detail button.

Thanks,
Tony

> TableViewController

```
    override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let theWidth = view.frame.size.width
    let theHeight = view.frame.size.height

    resultsTable.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, theWidth, theHeight)
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.

    refresher = UIRefreshControl()
    refresher.tintColor = UIColor.blackColor()
    refresher.addTarget(self, action: "refresh", forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.ValueChanged)
    self.resultsTable.addSubview(refresher)
}
```

> Detailviewcontroller

```
class ProductDetailViewController: UIViewController {

@IBOutlet weak var labelTitle: UILabel!
var labelTitleText = String()

  override func viewDidLoad()
  {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    labelTitle.text = labelTitleText
  }


  @IBAction func backButtonTapped(sender: AnyObject) {
     self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
  }
 }
```

Comment: How do you know that your table view is reloaded ?

Comment: I guess because It goes back to the top of my table view

Comment: Ok, In your tableViewController do you have a  viewDidAppear method ?

Comment: yes. my viewDidAppear is 
    override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {
        refreshResults()
    }

Comment: That's the problem, viewdidAppear is called when you come back from detail. so remove that refreshResults and it will be fine. 
You can for instance put it in viewDidLoad

Comment: OK. Got it. Thank you for your help.