# Back to table view from detail page without table reload

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uinavigationcontroller, tableview

Following is my hierarchy 
[Tab bar] -> [Navigation Controller] -> [VC containing table view] -> [Details VC]

In [VC containing table view] I'm fetching details from API in `viewWillAppear` and reloading table. `viewWillAppear` is also called when back button is clicked on Details VC. How do I prevent reloading table in this case?

My question is similar to this question [Back to table view from detail page without reload, Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34829752/back-to-table-view-from-detail-page-without-reload-swift) but I need to keep the table reload code in `viewWillAppear` as I've segmented control in this VC and I need to reload table when segments are switched.

Comment: As I've mentioned in my question I've Segmented Control in this VC and I need to reload table in viewWillAppear when segment is clicked. There are other things as well so it has got a bit complex. I want to keep table reload in viewWillAppear but just stop reloading table when this VC is loaded when coming back from detail VC. I can try using a flag but I was looking for any other standard solution if there are any?

Comment: Sorry, my mistake.  I was still thinking about your controller hierarchy and thought you were referring to the tabs as segments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can maintain a simple flag base mechanism to accomplish this. Declare a flag within your ViewController as follows

```
class YourViewController: UIViewController {

// MARK: Internal Variable
private var shouldReloadDataOnViewWillAppear: Bool = true


override viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)
    if shouldReloadDataOnViewWillAppear {
       // your code for reloading data
    }

    shouldReloadDataOnViewWillAppear = true
}
```

Now you can set `shouldReloadDataOnViewWillAppear` to `false` inside `prepareForSegue` or `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` which will restrict the data loading next time Your view controller re-appear on main window.